# How to Customise Header of DataGrid with Databound Itemscontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I tried to create a customized header of a `datagrid` containing an `itemscontrol`, which is bound to an `ObservableCollection<DateTime>`.

(Basically, I want to create 12 columns, one for each month-> see picture).

[image]

Why does this code does not work?

**Code**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgProjects"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}" AlternationCount="2" AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
...
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Monate}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ActualWidth}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}" Background="LightGreen" Margin="1"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
```

**Update** I narrowed the problem down to the Binding. The following code works finde

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}">                             
                <TextBlock Text="asdf" Background="LightGreen" Margin="1"/>
                <TextBlock Text="asdf" Background="LightGreen" Margin="1"/>
                <TextBlock Text="asdf" Background="LightGreen" Margin="1"/>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
```

**Update** Viewmodel

```
public class vmProjektplanung : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        ...
    #region "Monate"

    public event System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler OnMonateChanged;

    private List<DateTime> monate;

    public List<DateTime> Monate
    {
        get { return monate; }
        set { monate = value; OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Monate")); }
    }

    private void Monate_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        OnMonateChanged?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }

    #endregion
        ...
    }
```

Comment: How do you use that Template ?

Comment: It's inside a DataGrid. I just updated the code. Or did you mean something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem since your binding for the dates doesn't see the data context.

This should fix the issue by referencing the data grid by name.

```
<DataTemplate>
       <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Monate, ElementName=dgProjects}"
```

Comment: This did the trick. However, I have problems following the logic behind it. The template is specified within the grid itself, so why do I have to name it again?

Comment: the datacontext is not inherited, the only point is to recover the *lost* datacontext... maybe another example [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/12a5277f-16df-4899-9cad-b82c57e8fd9b/datacontext-lost-in-headertemplate?forum=wpf) where they say ... "There is no obvious choice for the source object of the header.Unless in this circumstance, that there is a way to do Databound column generation. That would explain why your HeaderTemplate isn't simply inheriting the DataContext from the top-level. " (of course it is a different situation)